# Гипотеза Коллатца

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

> Задача по гипотезе Коллатца:
>   нужно вывести число с наибольшим числом преобразований в указанном диапазоне.

Не работает, подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу?
Мой код:

```
def col(n):
for i in range(1, n):
    steps = 0
    if n % 2:
        n // 2
        steps +=1
    else:
         n = 3 * n + 1
        steps += 1
        return (i, max(steps))
```

Comment: во-первых обведите весь код и нажмите на кнопку { }

Comment: Сделала, а во вторых? )

Comment: установлен 3. 7 python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рабочий код:

```
def col(n):
    maxsteps = 0
    imax = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        t = i
        steps = 0
        while t > 1:
            if t % 2 == 0:
                t //= 2
            else:
                t = 3 * t + 1
            steps += 1
        if steps > maxsteps:
            maxsteps = steps
            imax = i
    return imax, maxsteps

print(col(10))
>> (9, 19)
```

Ошибки:
попытка работы в цикле не с переменной цикла, а с аргументом функции с его модификацией
`if n % 2:`  срабатывает для нечётных чисел
`return` вообще непонятно что возвращает
нет условия завершения цикла, когда пришли к единице (как и самого условного цикла)

Comment: *нет условия останова цикла* - вероятно Вы имеете ввиду "нет условия остано**вки** цикла"

Comment: @Alex Такой термин [тоже есть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5557y8b4.aspx), но в данном случае вы правы, лучше вообще "завершения"

Comment: Останова цикла, остановки цикла... Выхода из цикла! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
value = 6# Input number for task

print('Input number:', value, '\n')

while value > 1:

    if value % 2 == 0:# input value / 2
        value //= 2

    else: #if not shared to 2
        value = 3 * value + 1#3n + 1

    print(int(value))
```

Comment: Подскажите, а что делает ваш код?

Comment: value вставляете число и на выходе, если число четное, делите на два, иначе 3n + 1

Comment: Добавте караткое пояснение к вашему решению, его преимушества, возможно недостатки. Не пишите комментарии, [правте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1335279/edit) сам ответ.

Comment: Ваш ответ содержит что-то новое?

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from math import *

n = 1003
sp = list()
degree = 1

while n > 1:

    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2

    elif n % 2 == 1:
        n = 3 * n + 1

    if 2 ** degree == n:
        pass

    sp.append(n)

    if n == 4 or 2 or 1:
        true_one = n
        print(n)

    else:
        n += 1
        print(n)
```

Comment: Вы не ответили на уточняющие комментарии под предыдущим ответом, хотя прошло больше месяца.

Comment: вариант решения проблемы

Comment: Какой проблемы, подскажите, пожлуйста?

Comment: колатца. На входе число 1003 - это переменная, которую в начале подставляют

Comment: Вы не совсем внимательно читаете уточняющие комментерии. Вынужден повторится:  __не пишите комментарии, правте сам ответ__. Комментарии не являются составной частью ответа.